# add class when scroll to specific id ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add a class when the top of the window scrolls to a specific ID and removes class when scrolls back to the top. i am new to ReactJs and unsure how to accomplish this.

```
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

 scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
    document.getElementById("myID").className = "test";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myID").className = "";
  }
}
```

how can i use something like this in React? looking for a simple function that will handle this

Comment: How do find out if the window is scrolled to a particular id? or `<a href="#somethin"` clicking this link it'll navigate inside the page!

Comment: If you don't have the logic! First, we have to find if the id is in viewport! and then we have to write toggle classes!

Comment: i think you can use ref and achieve this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use var getBoundingClientRect and calculate the viewable element!

I have created [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vwskhh?file=index.js) link to the kind of fixing your problem! If you need further help comment

```
componentDidMount() {
    const getViewable = document.getElementById("start-editing");
    const that = this;
    window.addEventListener(
      "scroll",
      function(event) {
        if (that.isInViewport(getViewable)) {
          getViewable.classList.add("black");
          getViewable.classList.remove("gold");
        } else {
          getViewable.classList.add("gold");
          getViewable.classList.remove("black");
        }
      },
      false
    );
  }

  isInViewport = elem => {
    var bounding = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
      bounding.top >= 0 &&
      bounding.left >= 0 &&
      bounding.bottom <=
        (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
      bounding.right <=
        (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
  };
```

Comment: yep this is what i was looking for! thanks for the help. new to react and trying to wrap my head around it.